# Copying variable ranges and pasting to Multiple Tabs

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet, copying

I have a workbook that contains 51 Worksheets. Worksheet 3 ("Results") contains all of the data I need to parse out. I would like to loop through Worksheet 3 and copy 3 columns at a time, starting with columns CT-CV. CT-CV would then be pasted into "B1" of Worksheet 4. Then the macro would loop back to Worksheet 3 and copy CW-CZ and paste into "B1" of Worksheet 5. This loop would continue until all 51 worksheets have data (Go to column IG in Worksheet 3).

I have found a lot of macros to go the opposite way (Copy from many worksheets into one consolidated one) but none that go from consolidated data and parse it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to create an array of all of the destination worksheet names, then loop this array picking out the correct group of 3 matching columns (i.e. starting from column 98, 101, 104 and so on) from the source worksheet. Something like this seems to work:

```
Sub sCopyData()
    Dim aDest() As Variant
    Dim lngLoop As Long
    Dim strLeft As String
    Dim strRight As String
    aDest = Array("Data1", "Data2")
    For lngLoop = 0 To UBound(aDest)
        Sheets("Results").Select
        strLeft = Split(Cells(, 98 + (lngLoop * 3)).Address, "$")(1)
        strRight = Split(Cells(, 100 + (lngLoop * 3)).Address, "$")(1)
        Columns(strLeft & ":" & strRight).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(aDest(lngLoop)).Select
        Columns("B:B").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next lngLoop
End Sub
```

Regards,